# Is isParallel=true on test applied on deploy

Tags: apex, unit-test, deployment

We've got around 1k tests in our org. It takes 2 hours to execute all of them on deployment.
Could tests run in parallel on deployment with [isParallel=true](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_apex_annotation_istest_isparallel.htm) annotation?

Comment: I would imagine that something like this is testable by doing a mock deploy into a sandbox. Do a deploy without it, time it do a deploy with it, time it again.

Comment: If you haven't noticed it, you can now run only specified tests when deploying.  [More info.](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_deployment_change_sets_test_levels.htm)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this annotation will have no effect. From [Run Unit Test Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_unit_tests_running.htm) (emphasis mine):

> **Apex tests that run as part of a deployment always run synchronously and serially.**